# Is it possible to shrink botocore within site-packages?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, botocore

I've just seen that my web applications docker image is enormous. A 600-MB reason is the packages I install for it. The biggest single offender is botocore with 77.7 MB.

Apparently this is known behavior: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1629

Is it possible to redue that size?

### Analysis

- The `tar.gz` distribution is just 10.8 MB: https://pypi.org/project/botocore/#files
- 75MB are in [the `data` directory](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data)
- For every single AWS service, there seem to be [multiple folders](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data/ec2) (some kind of versioning?) and [a `service-2.json`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/data/ec2/2014-09-01/service-2.json)
- The `service-2.json` files probably use most of the space. They are not minified and they contain a lot of information that seems not to be necessary for running a production system (e.g. `description`).

Is there a way to either completely avoid botocore or in any other way reduce botocores size for the Docker image? (I'm only using S3)

Comment: There's also this ongoing discussion: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/2365